Fleck 5600MI Leaking at Head
My 5600MI is leaking at the head. New house and it was left like this. Can this be rebuilt? Would this fix it?
https://www.amazon.ca/AFWFilters-Softener-Rebuild-60102-00-Spacers/dp/B00FN2F71C/ref=asc_df_B00FN2F71C/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=292937658685&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12357748571958751934&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=t&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9001250&hvtargid=pla-306435036161&psc=1&mcid=dad7e5a65ad2348b88733910434feb34


If it's a newly built new house there's this thing called a warranty. If it's only a new-to-you house, probably not.
